# Adding an auto incremented column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, auto-increment

Given:

We have a table called Events which contains around 100 millions of rows for now:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AggregateId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [SourceType] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [SourceId] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetimeoffset](4) NOT NULL,
    [SerializedJson] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [EventDataType] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCepEvent_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [UData]
) ON [UData] TEXTIMAGE_ON [UData]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCepEvent] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCepEvent_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

We also have a non clustered index on SourceId column

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblCepEvent_SourceId] ON [dbo].[tblCepEvent] ([SourceId] ASC)
GO
```

Expectation:

We want to add a new integer column which contains auto incremented values in the same order as the Timestamp column for the existing rows. The idea behind; we are dealing with lots of data and some of them are having the same Timestamp value, so we want to be able to sort them in the order of the insertion.

Attempt:

To have the auto incremented values in the same order as the Timestamp column, I removed all existing indexes and then I created an ascending clustered index on the Timestamp column.

```
-- 1 - drop primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblCepEvent DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCepEvent_Id]
GO

-- 2- drop index on SourceId
DROP INDEX [IX_tblCepEvent_SourceId] ON dbo.tblCepEvent
GO

-- 3 - create a temporary asc clustered index on timestamp column
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_tblCepEvent_Timestamp] ON dbo.tblCepEvent ([Timestamp] ASC)
GO
```

Then I tried creating the new column.

```
-- 4 - create auto incremented column
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblCepEvent ADD OrderIndex BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
GO
```

After creating this column, I was planning to remove the temporary index on Timestamp column and go back and create the primary key and the non clustered index on the SourceId column.
But somehow something went wrong and the query locked the database, so I had to cancel the query.

Before this last try I tested this approach on a smaller set of data (1 million rows) and I observed that it does the job.
Now my question is: Is it a good way to go to achieve the expected results on a table with more than 100 millions of rows? Do you have any suggestions to meet this expectation more efficiently and in a more robust way?

Comment: Don't mess around with dropping and adding indexes, that isn't guaranteed to do what you want anyway. Add the integer column without `IDENTITY`. Fill it with sequential numbers using your desired ordering via `row_number` then either use a sequence instead of `identity` for future new values or use `ALTER TABLE... SWITCH` approach to make the column an `IDENTITY` column as a metadata only change

Comment: If you tried the same operation in SSMS and inspected the generated script you'd see it creates a *new* table with the `IDENTITY`, inserts all rows from the existing table to it then renames the tables. This is far more scaleable (and safer) for large tables. Using `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` is an even faster way to do this by swapping the data pages of one table for the other. The two tables must have the *same* schema though

Comment: In your case though, you can't depend on IDENTITY values to preserve the order of the SELECT query. For performance reasons IDENTITY values are pre-calculated, cached and assigned in batches. All those mechanisms will kick in when moving 100M rows. You'd have to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp)` to generate the ID values during insertion and add the `IDENTITY` constraint afterwards